# How can I prevent compilation errors from occurring inside std header (in Xcode)?

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, clang

Sometimes, Xcode shows compilation errors inside the std files.
How could I set it up so that it shows errors directly in my source file ?

[EDIT : please see comment under JBentley's answer for better understanding of what I'm looking for]

Here is an example : I know this code won't compile. What I want is Xcode to point the error here, not in the file `memory` (please see error below) :

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory> //

class B;

class A{
   std::unique_ptr<B> ptr;
};

int main(){ //(added after JBentley's answer)
   A a;
   return 0;
}
```

The error message :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr
/lib/c++/v1/memory:2424:27: Invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'B'
```

Comment: You should not be getting compile errors in standard headers. Please post an example (code + full error message).

Comment: The C++ standard library headers are already included as if with `-isystem`. This only suppresses warnings, not errors.

Comment: You're right ! I misunderstood that part. Thanks (edited)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in your own code, not in the standard header.

The following compiles fine [with GCC](https://ideone.com/43u5Ov), [Clang](http://goo.gl/xhrxoM), and MSVC:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class B;

class A{
   std::unique_ptr<B> ptr;
};
```

However, if you try to *instantiate* an object of type `A`, then you will get the error message you posted (which leads me to suspect you did not post the complete example that you are trying):

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class B;

class A{
   std::unique_ptr<B> ptr;
};

int main(){
   A a; // Error - B has not been defined
}
```

This is because you have provided a forward declaration for `B`, but no definition. The compiler needs to see the definition of `B` because you are using a smart pointer, which performs memory management. To fix the error, make sure the definition is known to the compiler prior to the point of instantiation.

Alternatively, if you use a raw pointer, then the compiler does not need to see the definition:

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
class B;

class A{
   B* ptr;
};

int main()
{
   A a; // No error
}
```

As for having the compiler show the error in your source file instead of in a standard header, it does do this in a roundabout way. The error message you posted is not the full message. Here is the full error message I get in Clang:

> In file included from
>   /tmp/gcc-explorer-compiler114426-23259-1w2uld/example.cpp:3:
>
> In file included from
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/memory:81:
>
> /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../include/c++/4.8/bits/unique_ptr.h:65:16: error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'B'
>
> static_assert(sizeof(_Tp)>0,

As you can see, this shows the hierarchy of files which lead to the error - my source file, `example.cpp` included `memory`, which included `unique_ptr.h`, which caused a compiler error due to the attempt to call the `sizeof` operator on an incomplete type `B`, which I declared in my source file.

Comment: "As for having the compiler show the error in your source file instead of in a standard header, it does do this in a roundabout way"
My question is about that part : How to avoid all this "roundabout" in Xcode ?